# echo within an echo statement when condition is met

Tags: php, echo

Is it possible to echo within an echo statement?

I have an if statement that echos a HTML element if a condition of time is met. I want to echo echo $rows['SOMETHING']; within this echo statment. so...

```
   if ($whatdayisit === Monday && $gmt <= $rows['opening_monday_to'] && $gmt >= $rows['opening_monday_from'])
          {
            echo'<div class="opening_times_times_orange"> ***** echo $rows['opening_monday_from'] . " " . "-" . " " $rows['opening_monday_to'] ***** </div>';
          } 

          else echo '<div class="opening_times_times_red">***** echo $rows['opening_monday_from'] . " " . "-" . " " $rows['opening_monday_to'] ***** </div>';
        ?>
```

I want to echo whats between the ***** but it wont allow me with the current script.

How do i fix this

```
if ($whatdayisit === Monday && $gmt <= $rows['opening_monday_to'] && $gmt >= $rows['opening_monday_from'])
{ 
echo'<div class="opening_times_times_orange"> HERE </div>';
} 
else echo '<div class="opening_times_times_red"> HERE </div>';
```

HERE (1) `echo $rows['opening_monday_from'];` and `echo $rows['opening_monday_to'];`
HERE (2) `echo $rows['opening_monday_from'];` and `echo $rows['opening_monday_to'];`

Comment: just do  echo'<div class="opening_times_times_orange">'.$rows['opening_monday_from'] . " " . "-" . " ".$rows['opening_monday_to'].'</div>';

Comment: <?php

if ($whatdayisit === Monday && $gmt <= $rows['opening_monday_to'] && $gmt >= $rows['opening_monday_from'])
{
 echo  '<div class="opening_times_times_orange"> ***** '
   . $rows['opening_monday_from'] - $rows['opening_monday_to']
   . ' ***** </div>';
} 
else{
 echo  '<div class="opening_times_times_red"> ***** '
   . $rows['opening_monday_from'] - $rows['opening_monday_to']
   . ' ***** </div>';
}

?>

Comment: Cant get it to work edidted with where i want to add the $rows['opening_monday_from']

Comment: @SpringheeledJack please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
if ($whatdayisit === Monday && $gmt <= $rows['opening_monday_to'] && $gmt >= $rows['opening_monday_from'])
          {
            echo'<div class="opening_times_times_orange"> *****'. $rows['opening_monday_from']. " " . "-" . " ".$rows['opening_monday_to'].' ***** </div>';
          } 

          else echo '<div class="opening_times_times_red">*****'.$rows['opening_monday_from'] . " " . "-" . " " .$rows['opening_monday_to'].' ***** </div>';
        ?>
```

Comment: Not working i have put another comment in the question

Comment: that values are coming from somewhere or not? if yes then it will work. i just edited my code check.

Comment: yes they are coming from a db

This works;

echo'<div class="opening_times_times_orange">'.$rows["opening_monday_from"].'</div>' ;

How do I add the other $row['opening_monday_to'] into this?

Comment: I just edited my code try it. or tell me all the values